# "periphery" and "perimeter" — are they the same?

Tags: meaning

I looked up in the dictionary and found they both mean the boundary of a closed curve, or the extended meaning “not the center”. Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have a close meaning and can be synonymous in some cases. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* lists one of the meanings of *perimeter*, “the outermost parts or boundary of an area or object,” which is also the main definition of *periphery*.

However, the most usual meaning of *perimeter* is geometrical: it means the line delimiting a figure or an object.

Comment: *perimeter* can also be used to indicate the length of said line.

Comment: There's a slight difference in the way the words are most commonly used. Often *perimeter* refers to the very edge of the area concerned - the boundary between it and the outside (*They were guarding the perimeter against intruders* i.e. they were guarding the border), whereas *periphery* refers to the area near that edge (*I used to live on the periphery of the city* - this doesn't mean that I lived right next to the city limits, just nearer the edge than to the centre).

Comment: @psmears: yes, that's what I meant with the last sentence in the answer. The primary meaning of perimeter is a line, a boundary, while the primary meaning of periphery is an area. But perimeter is widely used (and recorded in dictionaries) in a way that includes the meaning of periphery.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't meaning to contradict you - I just think it's not totally clear from how the answer's currently phrased that this is how the two words are most commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call these words unrelated (this is not going to be the "credited response" on a multiple choice test, but please hear me out.)  Here's an simple example to illustrate my thinking.  Suburbs lie outside of city centers.  There may be many suburbs outside of a city center at varying distances.  In every case, though, suburbs are "peripheral" to the city, that is, they are in an area outside of, but conceptually related to, the city center.  "Conceptually related to" is a fluid idea that may encompass geographic distance, commute times, home values, etc.  On the other hand, a state border is a defined, measurable boundary, or perimeter.  The conceptual "periphery" of a city center may lie within or outside of the city's state border, or perimeter.  The NY Metro area, for example, includes peripheral suburbs in NJ and CT.  The "perimeter" of New York State is not related to the configuration of the Metro, nor is the state border a mere concept used to describe any place outside of but conceptually related to New York City.  "Periphery" is the word that gets that job done.

Is this clear yet?  If not, read on.

Periphery?  Always used to refer to an object's location anywhere outside of a point of reference - either physical or metaphorical.  For example, "This discussion is on the periphery of the real topic at hand."  Or, "I was looking at the street light, but I could see a car coming from the left in my peripheral vision."

Perimeter?  A DEFINED BOUNDARY drawn around an area.

This is a tricky one, and certainly interesting.  But I'm going with NOT (usually, commonly, or necessarily) RELATED.

Comment: Can you please provide support for your answer? Sources for definitions, sources for quotes, etc?

Comment: @Jill Welcome to ELU!  I like the analysis, but I have to disagree with it.  Periphery = somewhere near the boundary.  Perimeter = the boundary.  Both words are from Greek roots, share the same prefix, and refer to the same general concept.

Comment: I mostly agree with this. I would say they are almost never fungible, few or no contexts when either/both could be used.  Periphery is for something that is less important; Perimeter is for something more important. The periphery cannot reliably be said to exist near the perimeter. "core areas in West and East Berlin, as revealed by patterns of construction,... Around its 100-mile perimeter, ... found itself at the periphery of West German life."  ronkirs.tn/pherimeter

Answer (score 0):

The difference is a matter of precision.

Perimeter refers to something very specific, well defined.
Periphery is a less specific area rather than a definite place or geometric object that separates.

Perimeter means the actual boundary line. It's a border, a delimiting line with a definite location that separates two or more areas.  It defines that which lies within from that which lies outside.

Mathematically a perimeter is a closed line bounding a plane area.  It is also the total length of that line.

Periphery is less specific.  That which lies outside of but near. How near is not necessarily defined although some definitions of periphery require it to be in contact with and touching the border or perimeter.

You would not say Los Angeles lies on the periphery of New York City but you might say that Yonkers is part of the  periphery of NYC.  Ditto with Jersey City.  All three do not lie within NYC but only Yonkers and Jersey City are close enough to be considered part of the periphery of NYC.  But what about Newark?  Some would say yes even though Newark does not lie on the border of NYC.  Long Beach? Paterson, NJ ?  That latter is probably pushing the definition of periphery.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as by adding supporting citations and references surrounded by your own words explaining why you think this is the right answer.

Comment: This would benefit from the inclusion of some dictionary definitions in support of the text.